# Error ao executar a aplicacao react native no emulador android

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, genymotion

[image: **error emulator**]

Nao consigo abrir um projeto React Native no emulador, já tentei usar o Genymotion e o Android Studio mas sempre ocorre o mesmo erro, quando executo: `sudo react-native run-android`

```
27 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 25 up-to-date
/bin/sh: 1: adb: not found
info Connecting to the development server...
warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": spawnSync adb ENOENT
info Starting the app...
```

Answer (score 2):

O Erro indica que o **adb** não foi encontrado:

```
/bin/sh: 1: adb: not found
```

Provavelmente se você tentar usar o comando `adb devices` em seu terminal ele deve informar o mesmo erro.

Uma solução para isso é você adicionar ao `$PATH` do sistema: o local do diretório da `platform-tools/` de seu **android-sdk**, exemplo:

```
PATH=$PATH:/exemplo-de-path-absoluto/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
export PATH
```

No meu computador eu deixo esse comando no final do arquivo `.bashrc` que fica no diretório do meu usuário: `/home/meu-usuario`

Lembando que se você adicionar o comando ao `.bashrc` você vai precisar 'recarregar' esse arquivo, para isso você pode usar o comando `source`[[1]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26696/280690) [[2]](https://superuser.com/a/46146/415069):

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

<sup>`~/` atalho para o diretório do usuário atual [[1]](https://askubuntu.com/q/85149/812459), ou seja, no meu caso `/home/meu-usuario`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Como o Icaro falou, vc precisa dar um set ou export da pasta em que fica o adb.exe para a variável de ambiente PATH, tenta ver se ela está lá com

```
echo $PATH | grep platform-tools.
```

Caso negativo você vai precisar verificar onde foi instalado o `platform-tools` *(quando instalou o Android SDK via Android Studio)* e editar sua `$PATH` de acordo:

```
export PATH=$PATH:</caminho/para/seu/Android/Sdk/platform-tools>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
adb -s reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

você tem que digitar isso no seu terminal para conectar com o aparelho conectado via usb